# icCube user friendly server URL using the application option

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Following the [post](https://www.iccube.com/support/how-to-web-reporting-apache-integration/) to set-up friendly URLs for the icCube server. How can you directly forward to an application?

I tried the example in the post to forward to a report. That works fine and I even added the parameter ic3demo for autologon to the demo, although I had to take care of the spaces:

```
RewriteRule ^/demo /icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&name=/shared/Demo\%20Finance/Financial\%20overview\%20v2 [PT,E=_ic3_rewritten:1,NE]
```

For the application I tried, similar to the line above, the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/demo /icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&ic3app=FinanceApp [PT,E=_ic3_rewritten:1,NE]
```

Unfortunately that does not work. In the log I see that it is rewritten correctly:

```
rewrite '/demo' -> '/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&ic3app=FinanceApp'
```

But the only thing I get is the reporting screen from which I can select a File.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: this is a question for apache not really for icCube

Comment: So it has nothing to do with a different treatment of ic3app and name as parameters. Please confirm and I will try to find my answer elsewhere. No problem.

Comment: Is the URL /icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&ic3app=FinanceApp working properly on the icCube server ?

Comment: Yes. That one just works.